# What is &darr; and &uparr; equivalent in Winforms?

Tags: winforms

I'm working on a legacy vb.net winform app, and would like to have have up and down arrows within my button controls.

I would think i need to invoke some sort of escape character sequence to have get the equivalent of &uparr; and &dnarr; ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open up "Character Map" (from Programs->Accessories->System Tools on WinXP).  You can find all sorts of interesting characters there.

Sometimes, you'll want to use weird fonts like WebDings or WingDings, but be careful to only use fonts that will be on the users's machines.)

Answer (score 0):

You can press ALT and type the unicode value for the character you want.  Consult this [table](http://unicode.org/charts/symbols.html#CombiningDiacriticalMarks), specifically the "arrows" section, and convert from HEX to DEC.